# Creating a VBS script, Need to change font format of Hyperlinks?

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a VBS script to create a signature in outlook, I have everything working alright but have two Links in there that are not the same size as the rest of the text.

The text is size 7 but the Links are coming out as size 11.

```
objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add objSelection.Range, strEmail, "", "", strEmail
```

this is how I am getting the links but no formatting seems to work.

Comment: Basop, Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please, do not add `Solved` in your questions title. This is **not** a forum, there are set of rules we follow here. I am sure you will get to know them if you stick around :) Please, see [**this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question) for further info. Also, if you found an answer to your question, please post it as an answer and accept it so other future visitors, or anyone else who wants to help can clearly see that your problem has been `Solved` already. Thank you

Comment: ahh cheers will do that, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK solved I ended up doing this, dont know exactly how it works (well sortof) but it does.

```
objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add objSelection.Range, strEmail, "", "", strEmail
objSelection.StartOf 3, 1 'selects the paragraph to be formatted
objSelection.Font.name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = 7
objSelection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'gets you back to writing the rest of the stuff
```